# Как корректно передать элемент в функцию angular?

Tags: angularjs

Пробую так:

```
<li  ng-repeat="li in list">
   <a ng-click="menu.clicked(li);">click</a>
   <div class="hide"></div>
</li>
```

js controller

```
controller: function ($scope) {
$scope.clicked = function (element) {
    $scope.click = !$scope.click;
    element.children(1).toggleClass("show");
}
```

Но не срабатывает, как это можно корректно сделать?

Comment: что не срабатывает? и повторюсь, если вы лезете в дом в контроллере значит вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: Это тот же самый елемент, его не нужно передавать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`li` в данном случае - не html элемент, а элемент(свойство) из массива(объекта) list.

Этот объект никак не связан с html.

Вместо этого надо использовать ng-show/ng-hide если надо скрыть показать элемент

Либо ng-class если надо применить определенный класс.

Например

```
<li  ng-repeat="li in list">
   <a ng-click="li.clicked=!li.clicked;">click</a>
   <div ng-class="{'hide':!li.clicked,'show':li.clicked}"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: а как быть в случая когда нужно показать только один элемент из всех li? т.е чтобы остальные закрывались при клике на какой то из li, и открытый был только он

Comment: @SdafsFasafs, это вы все еще аккордион мучаете? Сформулируйте конкретный вопрос и задайте его отдельно, опишите что вы хотите видеть, что у вас уже получилось, приведите пример кода, а так же в идеале - рабочий пример. К данному вопросу это отношения не имеет.

Comment: могу я как то с Вами связаться?) Вк скайп меил?

Comment: @SdafsFasafs, вы можете тут вопросы задавать, и еще тут есть чаты. :)